# On taking a whiz

Tags: discussion, tags

At the moment, Medical Sciences SE has tag [urinate-urination](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/urinate-urination). Why not rename it [urination](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/urination)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implemented as suggested in the question.